# Evaluating an NSPredicate on a NSArray (without filtering)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nspredicate

Is it possible to evaluate a NSPredicate on a NSArray, without having the NSPredicate starting to filter out objects in the array?

For instance, say I have the following predicate that just checks the number of objects in an array:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"count == 3"];
NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"uno", @"dos", @"volver", nil];
BOOL match = [pred evaluateWithObject:list];
```

This will crash, as pred will try to retrieve the "count" key from the first object in the array instead of the array itself.

Comment: It seems you have to evaluate with *list* not *@"123"*. And you can use the SIZE operator which is equivalent to *count* method of *NSArray*.

Comment: You are correct, I just fixed the typo

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the *SIZE* operator of *NSPredicate* which is equivalent to *count* method of *NSArray*.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF[SIZE] == 3"];
NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"uno", @"dos", @"volver", nil];
BOOL match = [pred evaluateWithObject:list];
```

Comment: Why would you go through this rather roundabout route? Just compare the `count` to `3` directly.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin, Yes. That is really the best way to do it. But the OP wanted to know why his predicate doesn't work, not what is the easiest way to compare an array's count ;-)

Comment: Thanks. I used this to filter an array of dictionaries by removing the entries where one key contained and empty array.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to using `[SIZE]` in your predicate format string is to do this:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"@count = 3"];
```

`@count` is one of the [simple collection keypath operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html) and is quite useful. It is far more common to use it than `[SIZE]`, although both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can create category with methods you need:

```
@interface NSPredicate (myCategory)
    - (BOOL)evaluateWithArray:(id)array;
    // other methods
@end
```

and in .m file implement it like this:

```
- (BOOL)evaluateWithArray:(id)array {
    if ([array isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        return [self evaluateWithObject:array];
    return NO;
}
```

Hope, it helps.