# NSPredicate interpreting a keyPath instead of a property

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a `Core Data` database of `Recipes`. Each `Recipe` has an `ingredients` relationship (many to many), so my `XYZRecipe` object has a `ingredients` property that points to an `NSSet` of `XYZIngredients`.

I want an `NSPredicate` to select all the `Recipes` that have more than 5 `ingredients` and tried this:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ingredients.count > 5"];
```

This fails, and complains that the class `XYZIngredient` is not key value compliant for `count`.

Clearly `"ingredients.count"` is being interpreted as a `keyPath` instead of returning the `ingredients` property of each recipe.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: did you try `@count`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548483/filtering-with-nspredicate-for-array-count-of-array-inside-dictionary-inside-ar/42548567 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805655/evaluating-an-nspredicate-on-a-nsarray-without-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to solve that problem on KVC side and on Core Data side:

KVC:

```
@"ingredients.@count > 5"
```

Should deliver the count of ingredients as the result of the key path.

Core Data:

```
@"ingredients[SIZE] > 5"
```