# Filtering with NSPredicate, for array count of Array inside dictionary inside array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have Array of format as below

```
[
   {
      "xyz" : [Array with different values];
      ... many more keys            
   },
   {
     .. same as above dictionary
   }
   ... many more dictionaries
]
```

Here see, i have Main Array of dictionaries, where each dictionary have different keys, in which there is "xyz" key, whose value is again an Array. Now i want those dictionaries for which, xyz's array must have count>2.

Now i have tried with following predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xyz.count>2"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [resultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but this is giving me error something like this, `xyz is not key-value complaint for key "count"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805655/evaluating-an-nspredicate-on-a-nsarray-without-filtering

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case that results in `-valueForKey: @"count"` being sent to each xyz instance, and xyz  isn't key value coding compliant for count.

Instead, use the `@count` operator to evaluate the count of the collection when you want the count then use

```
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xyz.@count>2"];
```

instead of

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xyz.count>2"];
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.0:

```
let fileterdArray = resultArray.filtered(using: NSPredicate.init(format: "xyz.@count>%d", 2))
```